# How to create a vector or list of tables in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a bunch of tables from a website. I would like to be able to store them all in one or more variables - basically for easy access.
The below code is what I have so far, I'm using the XML Package which I have found works well on a single table but can't get this to work for more than one table.

```
i <- 1
N <- 3
DSFL1<- 'http://website/results/2012_aussies_thu/results/'
DSFL2 <- '.html'
SportHTML <- vector(length=N)
vectorOfTables <- vector(length=N)

for ( i in i:N) {
  DSVL <- i
  SportHTML[i] <- paste(DSFL1,DSVL,DSFL2, sep="")
  Sport.table <- readHTMLTable(SportHTML[i], header=T, which=3,stringsAsFactors=F) 
  vectorOfTables[1] <- Sport.table
  i <- i + 1
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have a [1] instead of an [i] for vectorOfTables in the for loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your tables being objects of length > 1 (and possibly differing lengths), they must go into a list. So you should do:

```
vectorOfTables <- vector(mode = "list", length = N)
```

and when you assign inside the loop, do:

```
vectorOfTables[[i]] <- Sport.table
```

However, you can avoid a `for` loop and create a list using `lapply`:

```
SportHTML    <- paste0(DSFL1, 1:N, DSFL2)
ListOfTables <- lapply(SportHTML, readHTMLTable, header = TRUE,
                       which = 3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and it is also a lot more concise as you can see.

Comment: I knew there was a cleaner way of writing this without having to use loops. i love R! thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: If you write a loop in R, you're working too hard.  R has sophisticated facilities (lisp like) for working with lists which means you should never have to loop... :)